# How to get the hex colour of dynamic button

Tags: android, button, background-color

I understand that to set a hex colour of a dynamic button, you can write:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

But how can I get the colour of the button?

I need this as the button changes colour depending on clicks so I want to write and if statement depending on the colour of the button at the time.

After reading other various answers, they haven't worked for me, unfortunately.

I have tried:

```
Drawable buttonBackground = button.getBackground();

ColorDrawable buttonColour = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
```

But this will not allow me to make a comparison using hex codes, e.g.

```
if (buttonColour == "#FFFFFF"){

//do stuff
}
```

I have also tried to set the colour in values/colors

```
<color name="notPresent">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Then in my code:

```
String buttonColour= button.getResources().getString(R.color.notPresent);
```

Then made a comparison using an if statement, but this also fails.

Comment: you can try `buttonColour.getColor().equals(YOUR_HEX_COLOR)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button is a view. You can get solid color of view like this

```
int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
Drawable bg = view.getBackground();
if (bg instanceof ColorDrawable)
color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
```

Then convert it to color HEX like

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the int color not only button but any View**

```
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Rect mBounds;

public void initIfNeeded() {
  if(mBitmap == null) {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1,1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mBounds = new Rect();
  }
}

public int getBackgroundColor(View view) {
  // The actual color, not the id.
  int color = Color.BLACK;

  if(view.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      initIfNeeded();

      // If the ColorDrawable makes use of its bounds in the draw method,
      // we may not be able to get the color we want. This is not the usual
      // case before Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.1 r1).
      // Yet, we change the bounds temporarily, just to be sure that we are
      // successful.
      ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable)view.getBackground();

      mBounds.set(colorDrawable.getBounds()); // Save the original bounds.
      colorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 1, 1); // Change the bounds.

      colorDrawable.draw(mCanvas);
      color = mBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);

      colorDrawable.setBounds(mBounds); // Restore the original bounds.
    }
    else {
      color = ((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor();
    }
  }

  return color;
}
```

---

### Get the hex with the opacity

Hex Format of (#EE111000)

- first two chars are the opacity --> EE
- the next is the actual color 111000
  refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4) for more about opacity in hex.

**covert to hex without losing opacity**

```
  String hexColorWithOpacity = Integer.toHexString(intColorFromPreviosStep);
```